# Android code for connecting with php mySQL database

Tags: php, android, connectivity

I m working on mySQL and android connectivity through php
My App suddenly crashes when i write this code:

```
package com.googlecode.javacv.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.kosalgeek.genasync12.AsyncResponse;
import com.kosalgeek.genasync12.PostResponseAsyncTask;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AsyncResponse, View.OnClickListener {

    EditText etUsername, etPassword, etname;
    Button btnLogin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        etUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        etPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        etname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etname);
        btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void processFinish(String output) {
        Toast.makeText(this, output, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        HashMap postData= new HashMap();
        postData.put("txtUsername",etUsername.getText().toString());
        postData.put("txtPassword", etPassword.getText().toString());
        postData.put("name", etname.getText().toString());

        PostResponseAsyncTask task = new PostResponseAsyncTask (MainActivity.this , (AsyncResponse) postData);
        task.execute("http://theeatery.org/uet1.php");

    }

}
```

Is there any suggestion why it is so? Please help me to find out and fix the problem...
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are using my library from https://github.com/kosalgeek/generic_asynctask_v2. This new version constructor needs 3 parameters: 1) context, 2) HashMap, and 3) AsyncReponse.

What you have to do is:

1) change from:

```
PostResponseAsyncTask task = new PostResponseAsyncTask (MainActivity.this , (AsyncResponse) postData);
```

to:

```
PostResponseAsyncTask task = new PostResponseAsyncTask(MainActivity.this, postData, this);
```

2) Or better use it with an anonymous class to handle the AsyncResponse like this:

```
PostResponseAsyncTask task = new PostResponseAsyncTask(MainActivity.this, postData, new AsyncResponse() {
  @Override
  public void processFinish(String s) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
});
```